# How to count and echo the value

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have got a database with these two tables included - `questions` and `answers`.

Table definitions

```
questions - id, question, asked_by
answers - id, question_id(foreign key), answers, sent_by
```

I would like to count and echo the total number of answers for each question.

Sample data

```
question
id   question   asked_by
1    how r u    emma
2    r u ok     sam

answer
id   question_id answer sent_by
1        2       good    john
2        1       fine    sam
3        2       WTG     biggie
```

On the page that displays all questions, I want to write by each question and the number of answers. No. of answers for `question2= 2` and `question1=1`.

Comment: Well, for a situation like this, I prefer **join** to select rows From 2 tables [Read this tutorial on join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `INNER JOIN` and then `COUNT` entries for each question with the `GROUP BY` clause :

```
SELECT t1.id
     , COUNT(*)
FROM question t1
JOIN answer t2 ON t1.id = t2.question_id
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Comment: worked well but questions which have not got any answer do not show on the question page

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to first `COUNT`, `JOIN` and then `GROUP BY`

```
    SELECT q.question,count(*) AS answers FROM question q INNER JOIN answer a ON q.id=a.question.id
GROUP BY q.id
```

Comment: questions which have not got any answer do not show on the question page. thanks for the above